# How to insert a TOTAL column in this SQL Pivot query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a `SQL` `Pivot` query which works fine. However, I need to add a TOTAL column in the output (which will be the SUM of all the months).

My query (extract) stands as follows:

```
...

SELECT [Year],[Property], ISNULL([Jan],0) as [Jan], ISNULL([Feb],0) as [Feb], ISNULL([Mar],0) as [Mar], ISNULL([Apr],0) as [Apr], ISNULL([May],0) as [May], ISNULL([Jun],0) as [Jun],
       ISNULL([Jul],0) as [Jul], ISNULL([Aug],0) as [Aug], ISNULL([Sep],0) as [Sep], ISNULL([Oct],0) as [Oct], ISNULL([Nov],0) as [Nov], ISNULL([Dec],0) as [Dec]


FROM (

SELECT [MthName], [Year], [RN], [Property] from CTE1


UNION ALL

SELECT [MthName], [Year], [RN], [Property] from CTE2


)x

PIVOT(SUM(x.[RN]) 
      FOR x.[MthName] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable

ORDER BY  [Property], [Year] DESC
```

An extract of the output of this query is shown below:

```
 Year   Property    Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun   Jul   Aug     Sep   Oct   Nov    Dec
 2018   XYZ         3261    2955    3045    2118    1917    869   1772  1598    834   1254  537    415
 2017   XYZ         ...
```

I need to add a 'Total' column at the end of this output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this part at the last in your Select query:

```
(ISNULL([Jan],0)+ ISNULL([Feb],0) + ISNULL([Mar],0)+ ISNULL([Apr],0)+ ISNULL([May],0)+ ISNULL([Jun],0) + ISNULL([Jul],0)+ ISNULL([Aug],0)+ ISNULL([Sep],0)+ ISNULL([Oct],0) + ISNULL([Nov],0)+ ISNULL([Dec],0)) as [Total]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation approach instead of using *cte* with `PIVOT` operation

```
select Year, 
       Property,
       SUM(case when MthName = 'Jan' then RN else 0 end) Jan,
       SUM(case when MthName = 'Feb' then RN else 0 end) Feb,
       SUM(case when MthName = 'Mar' then RN else 0 end) Mar,
       ...
       SUM(RN) Total 
from table t
group by year, Property
```